# Rock , Paper , Scissors Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a rock , paper , scissors game . I cant seem to get the code to workout as regardless of the choices i made , the winner is always the computer ! Is my computer being bias ? 
Thank you for helping !

```
import random

comp_list = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
computer = c  = 0
command = p = 0

print("Scores: Computer " + str(c) + " player " + str(p))

while True:
    comp = random.choice(comp_list)
    command = input("rock , paper, scissors or quit :").lower()

    if command == comp :
        print("break even")
    elif command == "rock":
        if comp == "scissors":
            print("player won")
            p += 1
        else:
            print("computer won")
            c +=1
    elif command == "paper":
        if comp == "rock":
            print("player won")
            p += 1
        else :
            print("computer won")
            c += 1
    elif command == "scissors":
        if comp == "paper":
            print("player won")
            p += 1
        else :
            print("computer won")
            c += 1
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else :
        print("wrong command! ")


    print("Player: " + command)
    print("computer: " + comp)
    print("")
    print("Scores: Computer " + str(c) + " player " + str(p))
    print("")
```

Comment: You lower case the user's input, but the computer's choice is always title cased. Do better debugging - print what you're comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer always generates a uppercase string ex

```
Rock
```

and your input is always lowercase

```
rock
```

In python string cases matter so when you compare

```
if command == comp:
```

It's comparing

```
"Rock" == "rock" # -> which is false
```

You can fix your code by using all lowercase for your strings. Just change your array at the top to all lower case to

```
['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
```